# Need to display certain values for all columns start with 'BB%', 'ZZ%' for ID , ID2, ID3, ID4

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Name    ID  ID2 ID3 ID4 Match
1   BG234560                BB78458745
2   AC678900    BB7868877           ZZ5421896
3   AT9808744               BB546897
4   989878AC        BBIIT9807       ZZ5874896
5   A9045678                BB748596
6   BB98076 AC9800876           ZZ2536987
7   ZZ8793456   YY879654            BB4587961
8   UIT90876                ZZ365289
9   BH98048474      YYCC123456      BB6584123
10  FT7849562   ZZ56980T            ZZ6952314
11  3TY875759               BB258963
12  333IY78698              ZZ5463214
13  548I345     ZZ56980T        BB254879
14  OPQ4567 BB45678         BB258963
15  2345YYY             BB58214785

Name    ID  ID2 ID3 ID4 Match
2   AC678900    BB7868877           ZZ5421896
4   989878AC        BBIIT9807       ZZ5874896
6   BB98076 AC9800876           ZZ2536987
7   ZZ8793456   YY879654            BB4587961
10  FT7849562   ZZ56980T            ZZ6952314
13  548I345     ZZ56980T        BB254879
14  OPQ4567 BB45678         BB258963
```

[image]

```
declare @Drug table ([Name] int, ID varchar(64), ID2 varchar(64), ID3 varchar(64), ID4 varchar(64), [Match] varchar(64))

insert into @Drug ([Name], ID, ID2, ID3, ID4, [Match])
  select 1,   'BG234560',   null,        null,        null, 'BB78458745' union all
  select 2,   'AC678900',   'BB7868877', null,        null, 'ZZ5421896' union all
  select 3,   'AT9808744',  null,        null,        null, 'BB546897' union all
  select 4,   '989878AC',   null,        'BBIIT9807', null, 'ZZ5874896' union all
  select 5,   'A9045678',   null,        null,        null, 'BB748596' union all
  select 6,   'BB98076',    'AC9800876', null,        null, 'ZZ2536987' union all
  select 7,   'ZZ8793456',  'YY879654',  null,        null, 'BB4587961' union all
  select 8,   'UIT90876',   null,        null,        null, 'ZZ365289' union all
  select 9,   'BH98048474', null,       'YYCC123456', null, 'BB6584123' union all
  select 10,  'FT7849562',  'ZZ56980T',  null,        null, 'ZZ6952314' union all
  select 11,  '3TY875759',  null,        null,        null, 'BB258963' union all
  select 12,  '333IY78698', null,        null,        null, 'ZZ5463214' union all
  select 13,  '548I345',    null,        'ZZ56980T',  null, 'BB254879' union all
  select 14,  'OPQ4567',    'BB45678',   null,        null, 'BB258963' union all
  select 15,  '2345YYY',    null,        null,        null, 'BB58214785'

select *
from @Drug
where ID like 'BB%'
and ID like 'zz%'
and ID2 like 'BB%'
and ID2 like 'zz%'
and ID3 like 'BB%'
and ID3 like 'zz%'
and ID4 like 'BB%'
and ID4 like 'zz%'
```

But this gives no output

Comment: You don't want `AND` do you? That means it selects only rows where *EVERY* condition is true. You probably want `OR`?

Comment: "Or" is giving everything, not only 7 records.

Comment: `OR` works perfectly for me?

Comment: What logic do you want?  Do you need for all four columns to start with those values or any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select *
from Drug
where 'BB' IN (LEFT(ID,2), LEFT(ID2,2), LEFT(ID3,2), LEFT(ID4,2))
OR 'ZZ' IN (LEFT(ID,2), LEFT(ID2,2), LEFT(ID3,2), LEFT(ID4,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following where clause, you should get the required results.

```
where (ID like 'BB%' OR ID like 'ZZ%')
OR (ID2 like 'BB%' OR ID2 like 'ZZ%')
OR (ID3 like 'BB%' OR ID3 like 'ZZ%')
OR (ID4 like 'BB%' OR ID4 like 'ZZ%')
```

It will return all the rows with values starting with **BB** or **ZZ** from **ID, ID2, ID3, ID4**.

When you tried with an `AND` condition you don't get any results because its looking for the records with **ID, ID2, ID3, ID4** all columns need to have data with either **BB** or **ZZ**.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this, but you have to use `OR` clause across the board. Not exactly a cheap query though.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Drug]
WHERE [ID] LIKE 'BB%' OR [ID2] LIKE 'BB%' OR [ID3] LIKE 'BB%' OR [ID4] LIKE 'BB%'
OR [ID] LIKE 'ZZ%' OR [ID2] LIKE 'ZZ%' OR [ID3] LIKE 'ZZ%' OR [ID4] LIKE 'ZZ%';
```